# Why type unsigned makes std::variant<int64_t,uint64_t> ambiguous to construct?

Tags: c++, variant

I'd like to use simply `unsigned(123)` and `123u` rather than `123ul` and `(unsigned long)(123)`.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <variant>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   using var_t = variant<int64_t,uint64_t,double>;
   var_t v1{1};
   var_t v2{1ul};
   var_t v3{1u};  //ERROR
//   var_t v4{unsigned(1)};  //ERROR
   var_t v5{uint64_t(1)};
}
```

[live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74b644b776bec3a2)

Compiler output

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:10:15: error: no matching function for call to 'std::variant<long int, long unsigned int, double>::variant(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

   10 |    var_t v3{1u};  //ERROR

      |               ^

In file included from main.cpp:2:

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1402:2: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int _Np, class _Up, class ... _Args, class _Tp, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, std::initializer_list<_Up>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = _Np; _Up = _Up; _Args = {_Args ...}; _Tp = _Tp; <template-parameter-2-5> = <template-parameter-1-5>; _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1402 |  variant(in_place_index_t<_Np>, initializer_list<_Up> __il,

      |  ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1402:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:10:15: note:   mismatched types 'std::in_place_index_t<_Idx>' and 'unsigned int'

   10 |    var_t v3{1u};  //ERROR

      |               ^

In file included from main.cpp:2:

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1391:2: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int _Np, class ... _Args, class _Tp, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = _Np; _Args = {_Args ...}; _Tp = _Tp; <template-parameter-2-4> = <template-parameter-1-4>; _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1391 |  variant(in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&&... __args)

      |  ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1391:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:10:15: note:   mismatched types 'std::in_place_index_t<_Idx>' and 'unsigned int'

   10 |    var_t v3{1u};  //ERROR

      |               ^

In file included from main.cpp:2:

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1381:2: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Up, class ... _Args, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>, std::initializer_list<_Up>, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = _Tp; _Up = _Up; _Args = {_Args ...}; <template-parameter-2-4> = <template-parameter-1-4>; _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1381 |  variant(in_place_type_t<_Tp>, initializer_list<_Up> __il,

      |  ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1381:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:10:15: note:   mismatched types 'std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>' and 'unsigned int'

   10 |    var_t v3{1u};  //ERROR

      |               ^

In file included from main.cpp:2:

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1371:2: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class ... _Args, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = _Tp; _Args = {_Args ...}; <template-parameter-2-3> = <template-parameter-1-3>; _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1371 |  variant(in_place_type_t<_Tp>, _Args&&... __args)

      |  ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1371:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:10:15: note:   mismatched types 'std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>' and 'unsigned int'

   10 |    var_t v3{1u};  //ERROR

      |               ^

In file included from main.cpp:2:

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1361:2: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class, class, class _Tj, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = _Tp; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; <template-parameter-2-3> = <template-parameter-1-3>; _Tj = _Tj; <template-parameter-2-5> = <template-parameter-1-5>; _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1361 |  variant(_Tp&& __t)

      |  ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1361:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant: In substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> template<class _Tp, class> using __accepted_type = std::variant<_Types>::__to_type<__accepted_index<_Tp> > [with _Tp = unsigned int&&; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]':

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1357:9:   required from here

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1327:8: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'

 1327 |  using __accepted_type = __to_type<__accepted_index<_Tp>>;

      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1349:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::variant<_Types>&&) [with _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1349 |       variant(variant&&) = default;

      |       ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1349:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'std::variant<long int, long unsigned int, double>&&'

 1349 |       variant(variant&&) = default;

      |               ^~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1348:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(const std::variant<_Types>&) [with _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1348 |       variant(const variant& __rhs) = default;

      |       ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1348:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'const std::variant<long int, long unsigned int, double>&'

 1348 |       variant(const variant& __rhs) = default;

      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1347:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant() [with _Types = {long int, long unsigned int, double}]'

 1347 |       variant() = default;

      |       ^~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1347:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

main.cpp:10:10: warning: unused variable 'v3' [-Wunused-variable]

   10 |    var_t v3{1u};  //ERROR

      |          ^~
```

Comment: So there's an error message? Can you paste it?

Comment: In fact for my compiler (MSVC 19.27.29112) all four of these calls are ambiguous, because all four of them require doing integral promotions to find a suitable constructor overload, and promotion to `long long` and `unsigned long long` are both equally valid.

Comment: I added link to online compiler and listing from compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an elegant solution with extending std::variant:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <variant>
using namespace std;

struct var_t : variant<int64_t,uint64_t,double> {
    using variant<int64_t,uint64_t,double>::variant;
    constexpr var_t(unsigned u) : variant(uint64_t(u)) {}
};

int main()
{
   var_t v1{1};
   var_t v2{1ul};
   var_t v3{1u};  // VALID
   var_t v4{unsigned(1)};  // VALID
   var_t v5{uint64_t(1)};
}
```

[live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4d8767322322356)

No need to use cumbersome `in_place_type`. Sure it is useful but not this case.

*Thanks everybody for attention*

Answer (score 5):

[The final rule we landed on](https://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#14.sentence-1) for `variant` is that we consider only alternatives where the conversion is non-narrowing, and that narrowing determination considers the type, not the value.

Among other things:

- integer to floating point is always narrowing.
- signed to unsigned is always narrowing.
- unsigned to signed is narrowing if the signed type can't represent all possible values of the unsigned type.

So:

- For `v1`, the source type is `int`, the only non-narrowing alternative is `int64_t`, and it is chosen.
- For `v2`, the source type is `unsigned long`. If `sizeof(int64_t) == sizeof(unsigned long)`, as is the case for many platforms, then the only non-narrowing alternative is `uint64_t`, and that is chosen.
- For `v3`, the source type is `unsigned int`. If `int` is 32 bits then both `int64_t` and `uint64_t` are viable options, and neither is better than the other. So it is ambiguous.

For this kind of thing, it's a lot clearer to use `in_place_type` to explicitly pick which alternative you want, instead of asking the reader to do overload resolution in their head.

Comment: I'd prefer never use in_place_type. It is much more clearer to construct selected type directly and then pass it to constructor of variant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be platform dependent, but on my platform (64 bit linux + gcc C++) your results make perfect sense. Just note, in all below results conversion to `double` has lower rank than integral promotions, so it doesn't participate.

```
// Below works, as 1 is signed, and can only be promoted to int64_t.
variant<int64_t,uint64_t,double> v1{1};
// Below works, as 1ul is exactly unsigned long (64 bit for me), and is exact match
variant<int64_t,uint64_t,double> v2{1ul};
// Below doesn't work, as 1u is unsigned int, and can be equally promoted to int64_t and uint64_t - thus ambiguity
variant<int64_t,uint64_t,double> v3{1u};  //ERROR
// Below doesn't work, for exactly the same reason as one above.
variant<int64_t,uint64_t,double> v4{unsigned(1)};  //ERROR
```

}

Comment: Nitpick: there is no promotion from `int` to `int64_t`.